# Why is the repo instance passed in Repo.transcation/2 closure and Multi.run/3?

Tags: elixir, ecto

`Repo.transaction/2` can take a one-arity function that receives a repo instance:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:transaction/2

```
MyRepo.transaction(fn repo ->
  repo.insert!(%Post{})
end)
```

But why is the repo instance needed? Why can't the implemented callback of `Repo.insert!/1` be used within the transaction instead? Like so:

```
MyRepo.transaction(fn _repo ->
  MyRepo.insert!(%Post{})
end)
```

The same question applies to `Multi.run/3`, which also passes an instance of repo:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#run/3

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the history, here are the PRs that introduced them:

- In `Multi.run`: was added for when the repo isn't known in advance ([PR](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/pull/2272))
- In `Repo.transaction`: was added to be consistent with `Multi` ([PR](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/pull/3088))